# HTTP Code 400 getting objectfrom AWS S3 bucket with Boto3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli, boto3

I'm working on a script that is supposed to download a file from my s3 bucket and then make some changes on it. 
The problem is that my script **runs well when executed as root but does not when executed with the dedicated user**.

Here is the piece of code we are interested in :

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='xxx')

s3.download_file('my-bucket', 'my_file.csv', '/my/path/to/file.csv')
```

When I run the script as root, no problem, the file is downloaded and the script continues, but executed with my dedicated user :

`logstash:x:501:501::/home/logstash:/sbin/nologin`, it doesn't work.

I tried running Python interpreter as root and as logstash and executed the script command by command, it works as root but not as logstash. Here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 126, in download_file
extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 299, in download_file
future.result()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 73, in result
return self._coordinator.result()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 233, in result
raise self._exception
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

I searched a lot on google but there is no topic about this special 'user switch' case.

Comment: Have you followed [the steps](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration) logged in as logstash?

Comment: No, because I don't use them as root (and I don't want to). I use hardcoded credentials for portability (I know it's bad practice)... Credentials are in boto3.client arguments

Comment: Very strange, it is working for me.

Comment: Maybe the exception is misleading and you do not have permission to write into the directory where you start the python script from...

Comment: So stupid I was... `chown -R logstash: .` solved my problem. I must have forget a `-R` option on previous `chown`. Anyway, thank you !

Comment: Congratulations :) Make it an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into this error for the same reason I did:
For me the fix is to supply a **region** when initializing the s3-client like for example:

```
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="eu-central-1")
```

Where "eu-central-1" needs to be replaced by the region where the bucket really is.
It looks like it is this bug: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1413, though it sounds like it should be fixed.
Just for reference the two errors I encountered due to this region not being set are

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid`

And the one already stated in the question:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request`

Interestingly some calls did work in "eu-central-1" without that, while the same requests failed in China for "cn-north-1".

Answer (score 0):

I'm first :)

Are the permissions for the user `logstash` set correctly for the directory you are downloading into?

Did you by any chance miss the `-R` in `chown -R logstash`?

Comment: Sadly it was not the solution. Because when I've done the `chown -R` I already had the `file.csv` in my downloads directory (was previously downloaded as root). So I changed permission on it too, but the script executed as logstash failed to download the file by itself and use the previous file (as root & changed owner) to continue the process...

Comment: Have yout tried `chown -R logstash:logstash` for user and group?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in comment in your previous answer `chown -R logstash:` that does the same I think.

Comment: I don't know, if it is the same. I'd try it anyways :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I thought the cause might be the permissions of your user..

Comment: Finally I stopped my old VM, started a new one, installed scripts and confs and everything works fine now... So apparently, no solution. I think the only thing I did differently was installing boto3 as ec2-user with `sudo pip install boto3` (on the new VM) instead of `pip install boto3` as root on the old one. But I don't think that's the key.

Comment: Could be, though. In the end you got it, well done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. The problem was in the incorrect path to the file